# Не отобрадаются типы query-параметров в документации к FASTAPI, если использовать аннотация T | None

Tags: python-3.x, валидация, fastapi, параметры, pydantic-2.x

Прописываю для хендлер-функции аннотации по типу:

```
min_price: int | None = None
```

В итоге, в документации OpenAPI пропадает указание на требуемый тип переменной:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то это исправить, может стоит как-то по-другому аннотировать параметры? Ведь желательно, чтобы клиенты понимали, что тут предпологается int.